# React infinite loop returned by array even with dependency added

Tags: reactjs, loops, use-effect

I am trying to add the values of bookButton to the array, serviceList1 in the useEffect hook and this is what I came up with. The problem is, the array returned an infinite loop even when I have added the dependencies below.  `console.log(serviceList1)` returns an infinite loop of false, followed by trues eventhough so far my serviceList1 array has only one value, false.

```
const [serviceList, setServiceList] = useState([]);
var [bookButton, setBookButton] = useState(false);
const [serviceList1, setServiceList1] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8800/viewall')
        .then((response) => {
            setServiceList(response.data);
            serviceList.filter(function(serv){
                    if(serv.userId === userId){
                        setBookButton(false);
                        // setServiceList1([...serviceList1, bookButton]);
                        // setServiceList1(state => [...state, bookButton]);
                    }
                    else{
                        setBookButton(true);
                        // setServiceList1([...serviceList1, bookButton]);
                        // setServiceList1(state => [...state, bookButton]);
                    }
                setServiceList1([...serviceList1, bookButton]);
            }
            );

            console.log(serviceList1);
        })
    }, [serviceList1, serviceList, bookButton, userId]);
```

Anyone knows the problem with my code? Appreciate the help, thank you so much!

**EDIT:** I have tried removing the `bookButton`, `serviceList1`, `serviceList` dependencies, and now the array returns empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your effect updates `serviceList`, `serviceList1`, and `bookButton` when it runs, and because you've listed those as dependencies your effect runs whenever they change, hence the infinite loop.

Remove `serviceList`, `serviceList1`, and `bookButton` from the dependency list.

Comment: This also caused an infinite loop for my code at first! I only added the dependencies after that, and still got the same error.

Comment: Ok I tried maintaining only `userId`, and got an empty array instead

Comment: `serviceList1` won't be updated until the subsequent render, so your `console.log` inside the effect isn't going to show you the new value.

Comment: I have a map function for serviceList1, and it isn't showing the new value either.

Comment: Your `serviceList.filter` function is updating state for every item in serviceList. That's not what [filter is for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `setState` in each iteration of `serviceList` array by using filter method. That's leading to the infinite render loop.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  Axios.get('http://localhost:8800/viewall')
  .then((response) => {
      setServiceList(response.data);
      //if serv.userId === userId, Array.prototype.some will return true
      const hasBookButton = !response.data.some((serv) => serv.userId === userId)
      setBookButton(hasBookButton)
      setServiceList1(currentList => [...currentList, hasBookButton]);
  })
}, [userId]);
```